# Why I don't have access to env variable defined in gitlab-ci inside of my application?

Tags: python, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have defined variable in gitlab-ci UI called `MONGODB_URI` and I need to access this env variable inside of python application so I would be able to run my tests:

[image]

In code I access env variable:

```
os.environ.get('MONGODB_URI', 'localhost')
```

And in gitlab UI I have already defined `MONGODB_URI` variable, but when I push to master branch I get `localhost` not the real host URI I have set in env variable:

```
E pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5f64d00ff1b5a1546fd6c380, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

Do I have access to defined variables in my python application? How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add your `gitlab-ci.yml` job detail ? as you may know the gitlab-ci variables are only available on jobs.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/) says:

> Environment variables are part of the environment in which a process runs.

it then continues:

> GitLab reads the .gitlab-ci.yml file and sends the information to the runner, where the variables are exposed.

The same is true for [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and for the ones set in the UI

Now, as for "how to get them in your application" it will depend on how you are deploying your app.

If you are using docker/docker-compose for example, you can create a `.env` and reference that file in the `docker run` or `docker-compose.yml`

For Kubernetes, you could start with the same `.env` file, but would need to create a ConfigMap and reference it in your deployment.

Note that you can also build this `.env` dynamically in your pipeline jobs, I find this useful whenever I need the env variable both in the pipeline and in the application or if the value depends on the environment. Anyway, for this you can do: `echo -e "\nMY_ENV_VAR=$CI_ENV_VAR" >> my.env`